# jQuery "Chosen" on-filter event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I want to run a function whenever the search input box is changed in chosen (jquery dropdown plugin).
But unable to find such event neither in their documentation nor on the net. Does anyone have experienced or have idea how to call some code whenever search is done in Chosen?

I tried placing the jquery **.on('change'** event on the textbox but it didn't work.

I wrote

```
$(".chosen-search input").on("change", function(e) {
     //console.log($(this));
});
```

Comment: Try 'keyup' instead of 'change'

Comment: Maybe `input`? Something like: `$(".input").on("input", handler)`

Comment: yes, it worked with keyup. Thanks

Comment: @Thompson Rather use `input` as Jack has suggested. It fires also when changing the value via clipboard and when dropping some text to input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(".chosen-search").change(function(){

            console.log("changinn");
        });
```

This should work

Answer (score 4):

I had to "double" wrap the `on` to get the `input` event to fire on the Chosen text field search box:

```
  $('#my-chosen-input').on('chosen:showing_dropdown', function() {
    $('.chosen-search input').on('input', function() {
      // The text has changed, do something...
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Chosen js filters dropdown list `onkeyup` event. This snippet would work better:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.chosen-search input', function() {
    console.log('filtered');
})
```